# DLL project should be of which type for cross platform use

Tags: c#, c++, ios, ipad, dll

We have one application for both C# .NET and Apple iPad. This application will perform similar functionalities. For this we have one protocol layer which we are thinking to keep as common code. For this we are thinking of creating a C++ dll for the protocol module so that it can be used across both C# and iPad. For creating a C++ dll, I have a basic question:

While creating a dll project, which option should we select? We can create a dll for MFC, Win32, ATL etc. What would be the best option for my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use MFC as these are the [Microsoft Foundation Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) not available on iOS anyway. Probably Win32 would be your best guess - but make sure not to include any non-standard Windows header files if you want to use the DLL in non-Windows environments.

I would recommend to frequently compile your file in both environments. You might also want to take a look at multi-platform libraries like [boost](http://www.boost.org/) if you need advanced functionality.

Comment: Thanks. How can i compile my code for C# and Mac OS. I need to keep same one source and perform this task. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, as you already stated you want to place your common code in a C++ DLL. While developing this DLL, i think you have to use XCode to check iOS compatibility and another IDE (e.g. eclipse, Visual Studio) to build for Windows. Your DLL will expose functions that can be used from Objective-C and has to be wrapped for C#. For wrapping consider using SWIG or do it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for building C# apps on both Windows and iOS.

If you want to target the iPad, you need to build for iOS, not Mac OS.

You cannot build dynamic link libraries for iOS, only static libraries. Note, there are equivalents to DLLs on iOS, but only Apple can build them (or you can build them yourself if your iPad is jailbroken, but this will disqualify your app from the AppStore).

iOS is not related to Windows in any way, so Win32 libraries will not run on iOS. Your generic 'protocol module' (if you mean low-level code that can interface to other devices over TCP/IP or similar) will need to have significant differences depending on which platform it is running upon.